# How to add header text using css

Tags: html, css

I have the following html and this is part of the html in the header section of the site.

```
<body>
 <div id="headerMain" class="header flex-row start-xs">
   <div class="flex-col-xs-nofill">
     <div class="headerlogo> 
        <img src="image.svg" >
     </div>
   </div>
   <h1></h1>
 </div>
```

I am trying to give the header content as "MySite" as like below using css

```
 #headerMain h1:before {
 content: MySite
}
```

But this is not getting updated.
I am trying to find the solution and learn in the process.

Comment: Just wanted to give a heads-up that search engines won't pickup on the text inside the `<h1>` which isn't a problem inside application but if this is a marketing website, this can lead to a lower ranking on for example Google.

Comment: use quotes for text

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
 .header h1::before {
    content: "MySite";
 }
```

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/Stephen2hats/kos3Lmw4/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You must add quotes to attribute values on MySite. it works on me.
The code is like below:

```css
#headerMain h1:before {
  content : "Mysite";
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="headerMain" class="header flex-row start-xs">
   <div class="flex-col-xs-nofill">
     <div class="headerlogo> 
        <img src="image.svg" >
     </div>
   </div>
   <h1></h1>
</div>
```